# ASP.NET MVC theme editor on UI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant

I'm building a multi-tenant application that allows a tenant to edit the layout (HTML) on the UI in the administration control panel. I thought that I can build an editor for user to edit the razor view but It's need to be compiled to effect the new razor view.

I look into some open source applications. I find this one http://liquidmarkup.org/ It was developed for usage in Ruby on Rails web applications

Anybody have any experience & reference for this in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for but you could develop your site using jQuery themes (CSS and markup) and then use the [theme roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) for your clients?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can use Jquery Templates (http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) to meet your need.

Here is a random (greatly condensed) sample template from one of my projects:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Response Status</th>
    <th>Response Reason</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>${RepsonseStatus}</td>                
    <td>${ResponseReason}</td>
</tr>
```

Note the ${} tags - these will be replaced with json data at runtime.

And here is how to merge a template with its data

```
//myTemplate can be sent from a server side function
var myTemplate = SomeFunctionToGetMyTemplate();
//myData is a javascript object/json from the server
var myData = SomeFunctionToGetMyData();
//the html function just replaces the html of the context node (#myTargetDiv) with the //output of the $.tmpl function
$("#myTargetDiv").html($.tmpl(myTemplate, myData));
```

Jquery Templates are officially deprecated, but there is no official replacement from jquery yet (afaik). There are some helpful video tutorials on pluralsight for jquery templates.

Answer (score 0):

Highwire.com is built on ASP.NET but they use custom templating and custom UI abilities for clients using Apache Velocity Platform.

http://docs.highwire.com/apiv2/html/

Maybe you could use it as well

Comment: Thanks, I look into Highwire to learn how they're doing that. It seems that they've built their own framework for that. Highwire looks like shopify.com